# Split en Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola comunidad tengo un problema que no tengo idea de como resolver ni porque actua tan extraño. Espero que me puedan ayudar ya que llevo horas intentando de solucionarlo y no doy con esto que a simple vista se ve muy simple.

Tengo un input de tipo Select que al capturar su value con Jquery me entrega esto:

64555 | City | DE

Necesito el tercer elemento de ese valor por lo que estoy usando Split

```
var value = valueSplit.split("|");
```

Luego guardo el valor en una variable

```
var variable= value[2];
```

Que quiero hacer, yo quiero que si el valor obtenido es igual cumpla con una condicion

```
if (variable === "DE") 
{
   console.log("Es igual");
}
```

Sencillamente esto no funciona, el valor que obtube en el split pareciera que no es una cadena.

Que es lo que quiero hacer? lo que yo estoy buscando es que con ese valor ir a un dropdown y elegir un pais de una lista, pero no me funciona, al hacer una simple comparacion como la que les puse arriba no funciona.

Yo quiero hacer al final esta simple asignacion de valor en el dropdown.

Si hago esto, funciona

```
 $("#idCountry").val('DE');
 $('#idCountry').change();
```

Si hago esto, no funciona

```
 $("#idCountry").val(variable);
 $('#idCountry').change();
```

Ven el problema? No tengo idea de lo  que sucede. Gracias espero me den alguna idea.

Comment: el split es de javascript no de jQuery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Al parecer lo que te falla es que tienes espacios en blanco, mira el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
var valueSplit = "64555 | City | DE";

var value = valueSplit.split("|");

var variable= value[2];

if (variable.trim() === "DE") 
{
   console.log("Es igual");
}
```

Puedes usar la función `trim()` para remover los espacios en blanco.

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Hola... gracias! era esto (que verguenza).

Comment: Por nada compañero, que bueno que te fue útil, no hay de qué avergonzarse, esto le pasa a cualquiera xD.... Saludos =D.

Comment: Relax @joseangarita pasa más seguido de lo que crees :)

Answer (score 2):

No te funciona por que al hacer el `split()` estas dejando espacios en blanco, tienes dos formas de solucionarlo, una es teniendo en cuenta los espacios al momento de hacer el `split()`:

```js
var valueSplit = "64555 | City | DE"
var value = valueSplit.split(" | ");

var variable= value[2];

if (variable === "DE") 
{
   console.log("Es igual");
}
```

La otra es usando el método `trim()` el cual elimina los espacios en blanco al inicio y al final de una cadena:

```js
var valueSplit = "64555 | City | DE"
var value = valueSplit.split("|");

var variable= value[2].trim();

if (variable === "DE") 
{
   console.log("Es igual");
}
```